# Mostrar un valor de Firestore en un TextView - Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

tengo una colección guardada en Firestore, la cual se llama "Puntaje", ahí tengo guardado diferentes valores (todos son int). [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero es mostrar los valores en otro activity simple.

Traté con el siguiente código:

```
public void Resultado(View view) {

    noteref.get()
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
                    if (documentSnapshot.exists()){
                        String resultado = documentSnapshot.getString("Uid");

                        resul.setText(resultado);
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(ResultadoQ1.this, "No hay datos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

        }
    });
}
```

El problema es que al ejecutar el activity solo sale el aviso de "La app tiene problemas".

Agradeceré mucho la ayuda

Comment: que te tira en el logcat de la app cuando crashea ?

Answer (score 0):

Podrias intentar con lo siguiente

```
DocumentReference user = db.collection("puntaje").document(idDelPost);
        user.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener < DocumentSnapshot > () {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task < DocumentSnapshot > task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        DocumentSnapshot doc = task.getResult();
                        StringBuilder fields = new StringBuilder("");
                        fields.append("Score01: ").append(doc.get("score01"));
                        fields.append("\n Score02: ").append(doc.get("score02"));
                        fields.append("\n Score03: ").append(doc.get("score03"));
                        resul.setText(fields.toString());
                    }
                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                }
            });
```

donde idDelPost puede ser tu `mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()` o lo que hayas generado para esa id que contiene los datos. O tambien podes reemplazarlo por directamente el documento que quieras obtener, en este caso `498ZBk70KEjlL1v1Zkfp`  (te quedaria `.document("498ZBk70KEjlL1v1Zkfp");`)